# ajax request modal ordering with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to use modal window globally in my app, so set up on jquery's ajax complete and ajax start configurations. I am having an issue where modal windows called from within the ajax success callbacks are conflicting with my ajax notification modal, because they are not executing in the order I want.

In this demo, I want it to alert 1 then 2 then 3, but it is executing the success handler first...

http://jsfiddle.net/AsRxL/

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
    alert("1")
    $("#first").modal("show")
})
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
    alert("2")
    $("#first").modal("hide")
})

$.get('./',function(d, e){
    alert("3")
    // now the problem is the previous modal has not
    // yet fully dismissed
    $("#second").modal("show")
})
```

How can I get the ajaxComplete function to fire, and remove my notification modal before any callback functions are executed, which might themselves create modal windows?

Comment: modal does not disappear immediately, you might need to listen to hidden event as well

Answer (score 0):

The reason why they are not executing in order you want is in jQuery docs (http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/, http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/)

AjaxStart event triggers BEFORE your ajax request implementation.

AjaxComplete event triggers AFTER your ajax done implementation.

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
    alert("AjaxStart");
});

$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
    alert("AjaxComplete");
});

$.get('./',function(d, e){
    alert("Get A Start")
}).done(function(){
    alert("Get A Done");
});

$.get('./',function(d, e){
    alert("Get B Start")
}).done(function(){
    alert("Get B Done");
});
```

So if you run this fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/KbzCk/) you will see the correct order of execution.

If you are using bootstrap 3 modal, try checking Events section

```
$('#modal-id').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    //show another modal
})
```

Even though, showing so many modal windows does not seem like good approach.

If you are using modal just for notifications, try using toastr: http://www.johnpapa.net/toastr100beta/

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. Toastr is nice, but in our case, we need modal windows, to block ui until ajax calls are done.